# String to integer with .nextInt(); not working

Tags: java, string, int

Not to sure why the x.nextInt(); isn't working. What am I doing wrong?

```
    String w = "", x = JOptionPane.showInputDialog("Please enter the a"
        + "mount of attackers then the number of\ndefenders separa"
        + "ted by a space.", e + " " + f);
    int a = 0, d = 0, g = x.length(), h = 6;
    if("0 0".equals(x))
    {
        break;
    }
    e = b = x.nextInt();
```

Note: I would use an Integer.parseInt but I need to pull two numbers from this string, not just one

Also in some cases there is an " !" at the end for another operation.

Comment: what you get exception or something ?

Comment: "Cannot find symbol". I don't think it is seeing it as an operation. Is my Syntax wrong?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your code is a mess, so better clean it up a bit:

- Seperate initialization (`w=""`) from processing (`x = JOptionPane...`)
- Although it is possible in java don't declare multiple Variables with a single type-keyword (`String w,x`), most of all if you're doing initialization as well
- Use meaningful variable names, e.g. `inputString` is better than `x`

Then you'll see that `x` is a String and String-class doesn't have a `nextInt`-method that's only in `Scanner`-class. Since you need two values either split them (e.g. using `String`'s `split()`-method) before converting them to `int` via `Integer.parseInt()` or use two input dialogs (or best a custom dialog with two input-fields).

Comment: Ah, I didn't know it was exclusive to Scanners. I already have something else that works, I was just seeing if I could do it better. Thanks for the information and the tips for cleaning up my code.

Answer (score 0):

`x` is a `String` instance. And there are no method called `nextInt` in String class. You would need

```
e = b = Integer.parseInt(x);
```

After comment from OP

> I would do that but the input you would normally get from this program
>   is "# #" and I want to have those numbers separated

Then store each integer in an array and then parse them. Like

```
String[] integers = x.split(" ");
e = Integer.parseInt(integers[0]);
b = Integer.parseInt(integers[1]);
```

Again after OP's edit

> Also in some cases there is an " !" at the end for another operation.

```
String[] integers = x.split(" ");
try {
    e = Integer.parseInt(integers[0]);
} catch (NumberFormatException ex) {
    e = 0; // special character
}

try {
    b = Integer.parseInt(integers[1]);
} catch (NumberFormatException ex) {
    b = 0; // special character
}
```

Comment: I would do that but the input you would normally get from this program is "# #" and I want to have those numbers separated.

Comment: Again, would do so but it's a space between numbers, Also I forgot to mention that in some cases there is an "!" at the end for another operation.

Answer (score 0):

`x` is a `String` and you are firing `x.nextInt();` from string which does not compiles and produces compile time error stating

> The method nextInt() is undefined for the type String

Probably you need,

```
e = b = Integer.parseInt(x);
```

Since, you are asking for two integers which are separated by  space so you can split the `string` and get the two numbers.

```
String []numbers = x.split(" ");
e = Integer.parseInt(numbers[0]);
b = Integer.parseInt(numbers[1]);
```

Comment: I would do that but the input you would normally get from this program is "# #" and I want to have those numbers separated.